# Installing Ruby 2.2.3 on Ubuntu

Tags: ruby, linux, rvm

This problem probably has an obvious answer to anyone who has used Ruby on linux for a long time, but I can't really get a good answer via Google.

I'm trying to check out the Rails 5 beta, which requires Ruby 2.2.2 or greater.  I've installed the RVM (Ruby Version Manager) and set my ruby version to 2.2.3.  Running `rvm list` in the terminal results in the following output:

```
rvm rubies

=* ruby-2.2.3 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

Okay, great.  I have Ruby 2.2.3 installed.  Let's try `bundle update`:

```
Installing rack 2.0.0.alpha (was 1.6.4)

Gem::InstallError: rack requires Ruby version >= 2.2.2.
```

Okay, that's weird.  What version of ruby do I have?  Running `ruby -v` gives me this:

```
ruby 2.1.5p273 (2014-11-13) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
```

So... do I have 2.2.3 or not?  What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using `bundle`, I would suggest you to check your `Gemfile` for ruby version. You can also test it with `bundle exec ruby -v`

Also try:

```
rvm use ruby-2.2.3
bundle exec ruby -v
```

Comment: do you have `ruby 2.1.5` directive in your `Gemfile`?

Comment: Actually, here's what happened - I tried using rbenv, and now ruby -v shows that I'm using 2.2.3.  I put that directive in the Gemfile, and now running bundle update says I have 2.1.5.  That's probably because the project was initialized using ruby 2.1.5, but I have no idea how to resolve that.

Comment: @NmdMystery actually you don't need to put it there. I was thinking that your bundle activates ruby from the Gemfile, but if there was no such directive, you can just switch rvm to ruby-2.2.3 with `rvm use ruby-2.2.3` and try `bundle update` once again.

Comment: It's still telling me I have 2.1.5 :X

Comment: @NmdMystery you probably shouldn't use both version managers on one machine, but this is a suggestion. can you show your output after `rvm use ruby-2.2.3`? both `ruby -v` and `bundle exec ruby -v`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100174/discussion-between-nmdmystery-and-rustam-a-gasanov).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe by setting the default Ruby version on `rvm` to the one you have (ruby-2.2.3) solves the problem, by doing `rvm --default use ruby-2.2.3`. Then reload the bash and execute `ruby -v` to check if the default version of Ruby was changed properly and then try again to execute the `bundle install` command.

If you don't know `zsh` and `oh-my-zsh`, I highly recommend for this kind of things. You could configure the terminal in order to show you the current version of Ruby and Rails that you're using every moment. Check it here: http://ohmyz.sh/

Answer (score 0):

In addition to doing `rvm use --default 2.2.3` or `rvm use 2.2.3` make sure that you don't have the ruby package from apt (or whatever package manager) still installed. For some reason, that ruby package could take precedence over an RVM Ruby.

Also, try doing `rvm uninstall 2.1.5` to force your system to default to 2.2.3... You can always reinstall 2.1.5 later and, if this issue persists, 2.2.3 should stick as your default.